# how to determine an errant origin point's object?

Tags: vertices

How do you determine an errant origin point's object? This presumes there are many overlaying objects.

Comment: it's kinda... really hard to know what you're asking here but are you saying that you found a floating origin point and you don't know who's it is?

Comment: exactly. I'm a noob, can you tell? So I have this panoply of objects and there's this one origin point that wont' react to a click and is standing out in the open. I've gone down the outline, no change. I want to obliterate the little thing.

Comment: Hm.. By default origins are not shown on unselected objects. Is it possible you could upload the file?

Comment: You could try to increase the *Object Origin Size* in *User preferences > Interface*, or use the manipulator widget to move the associated object around.

Comment: @user961976 If it is selected, you can delete it, and read on the lower left hand side of the viewport the object name. To select it, try `Alt`+`RMB` and select what you think it is from the drop-down menu.

Comment: If clicking on it isn't working, try box select (B), circle select (C), or lasso select (Ctrl LMB).

Comment: It could be also an object with deleted geometry, thus only the origin would remain..

Comment: Given my still ham-handed Blender usage, I suspect it's the "deleted geometry" w only the origin remaining. Very grateful to all for your easy manner and helpfulness.

Comment: are you talking about the 3D cursor here? looks like a crosshairs?

Comment: No, not crosshairs, aka 3d Cursor.

Comment: As a closure to this, I just gave up and deleted the file.